# SELECT is not valid with DECIMAL in MySQL

Tags: sql, decimal

I tried executing a statement of a question in IBM book with the answer given but I got an error saying

**SELECT is not valid at this position**

```
SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY,
DECIMAL(SALARY*1.05,9,2) AS "INC-Y-SALARY",
DECIMAL(SALARY*1.05/12,9,2) AS "INC-M-SALARY"
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE SALARY*1.05 <= 20000
ORDER BY SALARY
```

The error disappeared when I replaced the second and third line with

```
SALARY*1.05 AS "INC-Y-SALARY",
SALARY*1.05/12 AS "INC-M-SALARY"
```

but the question needs these columns with two decimal places

Comment: You can't apply [IBM Db2-specific syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_decimal.html) to MySQL...

Comment: really? i didnt know.. the other questions were okay

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the OP is not using MySql. It's probably DB2.

Comment: @forpas but the question's title says "in MySQL"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, but in the comments above it's obvious that it is not MySql, this is why I asked the OP to set the correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution using truncate. i didn't know how to use truncate earlier...

```
SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY,
TRUNCATE((SALARY*1.05),2) AS "INC-Y-SALARY",
TRUNCATE((SALARY*1.05/12),2) AS "INC-M-SALARY"
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE SALARY*1.05 <= 20000
ORDER BY SALARY;
```

thanks for all help!

side note: i use MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `CAST()`?

```
SELECT LASTNAME, SALARY,
       CAST(SALARY*1.05 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS "INC-Y-SALARY",
       CAST(SALARY*1.05/12 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS "INC-M-SALARY"
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3da1b5d925d8242907729a08b349899) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @arina . . . Try it again, there was a typo.